# Removable Singularity in the Eguchi-Hanson Metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I am trying to understand the definition of the Eguchi-Hanson metric, and in particular the nature of the removable singularity at the origin when expressed as a metric on $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Background: On $\mathbb{C}^2$ with complex coordinates $z^1,z^2$, one looks for a rotationally symmetric Kahler metric of the form $\omega = i\partial\overline\partial \phi$, where $\phi = F(\rho)$ for $\rho = |z^1|^2+|z^2|^2$, with vanishing Ricci curvature. The only solutions are $ \omega_{Eucl} = i\partial\partial \rho$, which (up to scaling) is the Euclidean metric, and (up to some kind of scaling) the Eguchi-Hanson metric:
$$ \omega_{EH} = i\partial\overline\partial\left(\sqrt{\rho^2 + 1}+\log(\rho)-\log(1+\sqrt{\rho^2+1})\right) $$
Now this metric has a singularity at the origin (as $\rho \rightarrow 0$, the $\log(\rho)$ term is unbounded), but many sources say that on passing to the quotient $\frac{\mathbb{C}^2}{\mathbb{Z}_2}$, where $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acts by multiplication by $-1$, the singularity disappears. Could anyone explain how to see this using the above formulation?

Comment: [Related post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285637/is-the-eguchi-hanson-metric-a-metric-on-mathbbr-times-s3-or-tangent-bundle) on MO.

Comment: There is an excellent discussion of all this in $\S$10.2 of Joyce's book "Riemannian Holonomy Groups and Calibrated Geometry."  I'd also suggest looking at $\S$1.3 of Joyce's paper on the construction of compact $\text{G}_2$-holonomy manifolds.  In fact, that latter source might be the best place to start.  (Neither discussion assumes knowledge of $\text{G}_2$ anything.)

Comment: Joyce says everything better than I can, so I won't rehash it.  But I think it's important to note that the Eguchi-Hanson metrics are a 1-parameter family of complete (Ricci-flat, Kahler) metrics on the complex surface $T^*\mathbb{CP}^1$.  The complex surface $T^*\mathbb{CP}^1$ is biholomorphic to the blowup of $\mathbb{C}^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$ at the origin.